# Accessing a Browserify/Babel ES6 Module with ES5 Syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs, clojurescript

#### Context

I have an ES6/react-js file called `ExternalComponent.react.jsx`, with the following structure:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import Swipeable from 'react-swipeable'

    const ExternalComponent = React.createClass({
        //...
    })

    export default ExternalComponent
```

I have used browserify/babel to compile this file into its ES5 version (the new ES5 file is called `my-external-component-in-ES5.js`) using the following command:

```
browserify -t babelify --presets react MyExternalComponent.react.jsx -o my-external-component-in-ES5.js
```

The output of this file is quite large (>20,000 lines of javascript); however, it appears to wrap `ExternalComponent` in a large IIFE (might be wrong about this).

#### Problem

My goal is to access the class `ExternalComponent` from a pure ES5 context (in my development environment, I am unable to use ES6). I'm assuming this is going to involve one of the following:

1. Within `ExternalComponent.react.jsx`, somehow add `ExternalComponent` to the **global namespace**, so that when it compiles to ES5 I can just refer to `ExternalComponent` by its name.
2. Somehow access the `ExternalComponent` class which is buried in the massive `my-external-component-in-ES5.js` using ES5 syntax.

I'm not sure how to do either (1) or (2).

**NOTE:** In case anyone is wondering why I want to do this, it's because I'm trying to use the `ExternalComponent` within ClojureScript (which only has ES5 javascript interop; hence I have to figure out how to access `ExternalComponent` using *only* ES5 syntax!).

Comment: There is a (browserify?) option to create globals for module exports. Check the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile an ES6 module to ES5 with Browserify it converts the `import` syntax into CommonJS calls.

This:

```
import foo from './foobar';
```

Becomes:

```
var foo = require('./foobar');
```

You can access and use your class exactly as you would expect from your ES5 file, there's no need to clobber the global namespace. Just use the CommonJS functions.

```
var ExternalComponent = require('./my-external-component-in-ES5');

ReactDOM.render
  <ExternalComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

---

If you're trying to do this from ClojureScript, then I suggest creating a standalone browserify build that exposes your modules with global variables. You can use a tool like [`browserify-umdify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-umdify).

```
// external-component.js
export default ExternalComponent
```

This will be compiled to a Javascript file that exposes `externalComponent` as a global variable on the window object.

Compile it to somewhere like `resources/public/js/compiled/bundled-deps.js`, then add it to your `index.html` with a script tag (above your cljs build).

Then you'll be able to reference your JS modules through the JS namespace.

```
(def external-component js/ExternalComponent)
```

Comment: This is helpful, but unfortunately -- AFAIK at least -- I'm unable to make CommonJS calls to `require` within ClojureScript (I'm only able to use pure ES5 syntax).

Comment: @George Updated answer.

Comment: Excellent answer; I appreciated the clojurescript specific response.